# How to check hyperlink status using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova

I created a dynamic list with hyperlinks using Android [PhoneGap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PhoneGap). Now I want to check the link status (that is, whether the link is clicked or not) each time I run that application.

Comment: You mean you want to know if the link was visited? If so: not possible hopefully. http://dbaron.org/mozilla/visited-privacy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an attribute to link "onclick" and do something on `onclick`. There is also to be a counter variable to differentiate the links. Like this:

```
<a onclick="alert('clikced'+counter)">Link</a>
```

Or you can call any JavaScript function on the `onclick` event.

Answer (score 0):

You can add event to every link, when it is clicked, `count++`, and save `count` to local storage or something else. When run the application next time, check out `count` for each link.

Answer (score 0):

```
function linkisclicked(){
    //Do your tasks
}    

<a onclick="linkisclicked()"> link </a>
```